# A simple YES in a cell in column A triggers EMAIL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've searched through the forums and the answer is most likely out there but I need some assistance.

If the letter "Y" is input in column A, I need an automatic email triggered to a predetermined list of people. Ideally, this email would include an automatically generated email body according to the row data (Item, vendor, total, job, etc.).

This is what I have written so far. It sends an email out *every* time I make a change. I have tried, unsuccessfully, to refine the project's triggers and the `if (Index of)` bit.

```
  function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "me@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('A')!="Y"){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there!

In your `if` statment:

```
if(cell.indexOf('A')!="Y"){
```

You need to evaluate two things, first if the user is editing the column A and second if the value of the cell is "Y".

For the first one, you already have the value of the current cell in `cellvalue`, so just evaluate if `cellvalue == "Y"`.

For the second one, you need to evaluate if the user is editing the column A, you can use `.getColumnIndex()`this will get the index of the range, in this case the cell, column A will return `1`, so you evaluate `sheet.getActiveCell().getColumnIndex() == 1`

Now, you just need to use the [logical operator &&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) to check if both expressions evaluate to true.

Your line should look like this:

```
if(cellvalue == "Y" && sheet.getActiveCell().getColumnIndex() == 1){
```

Finally to make sure the email is sent only if the line above evaluates to true, move the `subject`, `body` and  `MailApp`inside the if statement:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "me@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cellvalue == "Y" && sheet.getActiveCell().getColumnIndex() == 1){
    message = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
    var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
};
```

Comment: Absolute lifesaver!